# Blazor - Call JavaScript from C# class

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, blazor, webassembly

Here is what I want to achieve:

I have a (normal) class in a Blazor WASM project. I want to invoke a JavaScript function from my class.
If I want to do this from a Razor component it is working fine, I inject IJSruntime and invokevoidasync to my JavaScript.

But it goes wrong when I try to do it from a class.
First I tried to inject it like this:

```
[Inject]
IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
```

But ended up with error message: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'jsRuntime')
I learned from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628714/blazor-client-wasm-jsinvoke-value-cannot-be-null-error) post that I have to "Inject it in the traditonal way", so I did this:

```
public class InvokeJavaScript
{
    private readonly IJSRuntime jSRuntime;

    public InvokeJavaScript(IJSRuntime jSRuntime)
    {
        this.jSRuntime = jSRuntime;
    }

    public async void InvokeMyJs()
    {
        await jSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("giveMeAMessage");
    }
}
```

But from there on I am stuck, I know that this must be some key .NET knowledge but I am missing a piece here.. I want to call the "InvokeMyJs" methode like:

```
InvokeJavaScript ij = new InvokeJavaScript();
ij.InvokeMyJs();
```

But know I am facing an error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'jSRuntime' of 'InvokeJavaScript.InvokeJavaScript(IJSRuntime)'

That I get the error makes sense to me but I dont know how to fix it, what parameter must I send to InvokeJavaScript(IJSRuntime jSRuntime) and how do I do it correctly? Can anyone give an example?

Comment: You need to provide your class `InvokeJavaScript` for injection. Something like `services.AddScoped<InvokeJavaScript>()`....

Comment: Ok, I added that to my startup class, but how to go from there?

Comment: This class is then injectable. You can then inject it into any component you want.

Comment: Also, be very carful with `async void`. Better make it `async Task` and await it unless you are very very sure you need fire&forget mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use DI you have to follow it through.
In general that means avoiding `new`, as in:

```
InvokeJavaScript ij = new InvokeJavaScript();  // no parameter
```

- register the InvokeJavaScript as a Service in Startup.
- inject it where you need it.

#### Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<InvokeJavaScript>();
```

#### SomeComponent.razor

```
@inject InvokeJavaScript ij
```

Comment: Ok, so this is for injecting it to Razor, but how can i make this work from a "normal" class? So call the Invokemyjs methode in my InvokeJavaScript class from another class?

Comment: Same trick again: inject it. And thus registrer that "normal" class as injectable too. As I said, DI all the way.