# Problem with [Inject], not working in C# class (Blazor)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor

I want to trigger a JavaScript function from .net class in a Blazor Wasm project.
I created a class (client side)

```
  public class InvokeMyJavaScript
{
   private readonly IJSRuntime jSRuntime;

   public InvokeMyJavaScript(IJSRuntime jSRuntime)
   {
      this.jSRuntime = jSRuntime;
   }

   public async ValueTask InvokeMyJs()
   {
      await jSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("giveMeAMessage");
   }
}
```

I added to Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<InvokeJavaScript>();
```

In my Razor component I now can do this:

```
[Inject]
InvokeMyJavaScript imjs { get; set; }

public async void InvokeMyJs()
{
   await imjs.InvokeMyJs();
}
```

Works perfectly, thanks to the people who helped me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68664268/blazor-call-javascript-from-c-sharp-class). but when I try to do this from a class it goes wrong.
I tried:

```
[Inject]
InvokeMyJavaScript ij { get; set; }

private async Task TestnaarJs()
{
   await ij.InvokeMyJs();
}
```

But then I receive an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I cant figure out what is going wrong... How can I inject in a class?

Comment: `[Inject]` attribute will work for component. In order to inject into a normal class then use constructor injection. [Read more about that here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server#use-di-in-services)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[Inject]` attribute is meant to work for components, but in order to inject into a normal classes then use constructor injection. [Read more about that here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server#use-di-in-services)

> `@inject` (or the `[Inject]` attribute) isn't available for use in services. Constructor injection must be used instead. Required services are added by adding parameters to the service's constructor.

```
//...

private InvokeMyJavaScript ij;

//CTOR
public MyServiceClass(InvokeMyJavaScript ij) {
    this.ij = ij;
}

private async Task TestnaarJs() {
   await ij.InvokeMyJs();
}

//...
```

Additionally I would suggest abstracting `InvokeMyJavaScript` behind an interface and injecting the abstraction instead of the concrete implementation to avoid tight coupling to implementation details/concerns.

Comment: Yes! Thats it. It works, I was thinking to hard. Thanks for the clear answer!

Comment: Can't get this to work for me.  I have a console app with a reference to a Blazor Server app. In the Blazor app I have a Utilities class which is called from the console app.  I need my database service in the Utilities class. I have a constructor for the utilities class with the db service type as a parameter, just like the above example, not sure why it's not working...